# rewrite condition redirects instead of rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

Iam trying to rewrite my URL `http://givehands.co.in/post.php?p=post&id=1` to `http://givehands.co.in/post/1/` using htacess.

But it gets redirected to the URL `http://givehands.co.in/post.php?p=post&id=1` instead of rewriting it? My domain givehands is mapped to a sub directory of my webserver.

Could any one help me out with the correct rewrite rule? Iam new to this.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post/(.*)
RewriteRule post/(.*)/ http://givehands.co.in/post.php?p=post&id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post/
RewriteRule post/ http://givehands.co.in/post.php [L]
```

Comment: Post your .htaccess content. Probably you have `[L,R]` when you should have only `[L]`

Comment: Without the contents of your .htaccess file one could not reliably answer your question.

Comment: I have updated my htacess content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache rewrite rule - prevent rewritten URL appearing in browser URL bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340205/apache-rewrite-rule-prevent-rewritten-url-appearing-in-browser-url-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a full URL in your redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post/ 
RewriteRule post/ http://givehands.co.in/post.php [L]
```

Putting a full URL in there forces Apache to redirect the browser instead of rewriting it:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> **Absolute URL**
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the
>   scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated
>   as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the
>   given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see
>   the [R] flag below.

If givehands.co.in is the domain you're hosting, try changing it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} post/ 
RewriteRule post/ /post.php [L]
```

If givehands.co.in isn't on your server, or is under a different VirtualHost, then there's no way<sup>†</sup> to "rewrite" the URL, you have to redirect the browser (which is why Apache is taking the lead and doing this for you).

<sup>†</sup> You could actually setup a reverse proxy to do something like this, but that's probably a topic for a different discussion :)