# How to stop htaccess rewrite rule updating browser URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've read through many of the similar requests such as:

[Apache rewrite rule - prevent rewritten URL appearing in browser URL bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340205/apache-rewrite-rule-prevent-rewritten-url-appearing-in-browser-url-bar)

But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using codeigniter 3 and it's root is at the following location:

```
https://example.com/api/v1.0
```

I've set up a basic route and all is working fine with Codeigniter E.g.  If I navigate to:

```
/api/v1.0/index.php/pages/view/about
```

the appropriate page appears so all seams well. What I really want is for the URL to get rewritten so that when I enter:

```
/api/v1.0/pages/view/about
```

it goes to the same page. I've added a htaccess file that rewrites the rule and all works as expected:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/v1.0/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is, when I enter the the url:

```
/api/v1.0/pages/view/about
```

it goes to the correct page, but the browser URL gets updated to:

```
/api/v1.0/index.php/pages/view/about
```

My question is, how can I stop the browser URL from being updated?

Update - my web servers site behind an AWS ELB that acts as the https end point. I have the following in the httpd.conf to ensure that any non 'www' prefixed URLS and any http calls are redirected to https://www

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^signup\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't think this rule is causing an issue as its not being invoked, I'm providing the correct prefix and protocol.

Many thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much testing it would appear that my virtual host settings in httpd.conf were causing the issue. If I removed these rules and then the local .htaccess rules worked exactly as expected.

I've removed the local .htaccess rules and added the following to rule to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteRule    ^/api/v1\.0/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)/?$    /api/v1.0/index\.php/$1    [NC,L,QSA]    # Process API Call
```

My Virtual Host section now looks like this:

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^signup\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^/api/v1\.0/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)/?$    /api/v1.0/index\.php/$1    [NC,L,QSA]    # Process API Call
```

So now calls to:

```
/api/v1.0/some/directory
```

Will get rewritten to this:

```
/api/v1.0/index.php/some/directory
```

And this happens without redirecting the browser or affecting the browser URL. What I don't understand is why this is not entering into an infinite loop as I have no rewrite precondition to check for calls to the /api/v1.0/index.php/*

Anybody know why this is no entering into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check that `index.php` isn't set for `$config['index_page']`.

If it is change it to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is set as follows: $config['index_page'] = '';