# .htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, subdomain

Is it possible to use `.htaccess` to rewrite a sub domain to a directory?

Example:

- `http://sub.domain.example/`

shows the content of

- `http://domain.example/subdomains/sub/`

Answer (score 117):

Try putting this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

For a more general rule (that works with any subdomain, not just `sub`) replace the last two lines with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Ansari's solution will work, however, it when I navigate to `http://test.domain.com`, the URL redirects me to `http://test.domain.com/subdomains/test/`. Is it possible without showing the `/subdomains/test/` at the end?

Comment: You mean it redirects to `http://domain.com/subdomains/test`? And you want the redirection to be invisible?

Comment: In that case, I believe you will have to look into using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) and specify a `P` flag in addition to the `L`.

Comment: No, it redirects to `http://test.domain.com/subdomains/test/`, when I only want it to show `http://test.domain.com/`

Comment: I can't see how it redirects to `test.domain.com/subdomains/test` - maybe there is something else going on here. Can you add `RewriteBase /` right after `RewriteEngine on`? Also, if you want to keep it showing `test.domain.com` you will have to use mod_proxy and the `[P]` flag.

Comment: How do I implement the mod_proxy?

Also, adding `RewriteBase /` breaks the script and makes it display the index page of the root folder.

Comment: I need a portable solution without explicit domain name.

Comment: @TomášZato make a new question :)

Comment: See Lee Kowalkowski's answer above if you want to keep just the subdomain visible and not display the whole path in the browser.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using @anubhava's answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395008/128984

Comment: It was redirecting to `*/subdomains/test` because of this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`. You could replace it by `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: It could be a version error, perhaps, but ditto @anubhava's answer (see Micah's comment above). Worked for me when this answer did not.

Comment: can i mask the url in this way, i need this answer, but it redirects to the folder path, i want to preserve the subdomain url in address bar, any way ????

Comment: It redirects because the RewriteRule target contains "http://". You need to remove the domain. This means `http://example.com/subdomains/%1/$1` should be `subdomains/%1/$1`. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165787/318765

Answer (score 53):

I'm not a mod_rewrite expert and often struggle with it, but I have done this on one of my sites. It might need other flags, etc., depending on your circumstances.  I'm using this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/subdomain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/subdomain/$1 [L]
```

Any other rewrite rules for the rest of the site must go afterwards to prevent them from interfering with your subdomain rewrites.

Comment: I would say so. I found this setting is the right one as the same as my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29363720/4058484).

Comment: Just as a reference, in case someone beginning with `.htaccess` comes to this page (like I did), besides creating the actual `.htaccess` file, for it to become effective, you need to set `AllowOverride` in your `VirtualHost` settings (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22819550/1657502), enable Apache's `rewrite` module and then restart Apache (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/1657502)

Comment: This wont work if you use www to visit subdomain. @Minh solution will work in all cases.

Comment: @RohanKhude, do you mean if you want www.example.com and example.com to serve different content?  Because usually, for SEO, you would have www.example.com to issue a permanent redirect to example.com or vice versa.

Comment: No, I just meant to say above htaccess snippet is not working when i visit www.subdomain.example.com.

Comment: @RohanKhude www as a subdomain of a subdomain is also something you'd also have to get to work at the DNS level, isn't it?  I think your expectation that it should work for any arbitrary subdomain is incorrect. Minh's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41389905/30945) assumes your .htaccess configuration supports 1 and only 1 subdomain, so is less robust in that aspect.  My solution supports as many subdomains as you need, but yes, you need to explicitly define every supported subdomain, but an optional `www.` prefix is probably best supported via a redirect than a rewrite.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the following rule in [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) to rewrite a subdomain to a subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine On

 # If the host is "sub.domain.example"
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.example$ [NC]
 # Then rewrite any request to /folder
 RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Line-by-line explanation:

```
  RewriteEngine on
```

The line above tells the server to turn on the engine for rewriting URLs.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.example$ [NC]
```

This line is a condition for the RewriteRule where we match against the HTTP host using a regex pattern. The condition says that if the host is `sub.domain.example` then execute the rule.

```
 RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

The rule matches `http://sub.domain.example/foo` and internally redirects it to `http://sub.domain.example/folder/foo`.

Replace `sub.domain.example` with your subdomain and folder with name of the folder you want to point your subdomain to.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me - explanation of how I got here as follows. Arrived here looking for an age old problem with subdomain redirect that broke apparently when I installed SSL on the main site TLD. The redirect was initially still trying to use the main site TLD still and breaking security rules. What I needed was the keep the subdomain (that was on a completely different TLD) on the same host but away from the main site. Adding a rewrite rule as above enabled me to forward the complete subdomain to the folder hosted under the main TLD site.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and found a detailed explanation in http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3163397.htm

My solution (the subdomains contents should be in a folder called `sd_subdomain`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.domain\.example
RewriteCond $1 !^sd_
RewriteRule (.*) /sd_subdomain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, must I configure something in the dns zone of the domain ?

Comment: @totoaussi you should create an * A record or an A record per subdomain, pointing to the same server.

Answer (score 4):

This redirects to the same folder to a subdomain:

#### .httaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain\.example/subdomains/%1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to putting this *.htaccess* file in the subdomain folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ ./subdomains/sub/$1
```

It redirects to *http://example.org/subdomains/sub/*, when you only want it to show *http://sub.example.org/*.

Comment: The question was asked in 2012 and has 8 answers.  Does your answer add value at this point?

Comment: This solution will work even if you use www to visit subdomain

Answer (score 2):

Redirect subdomain directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(archive\.example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%2/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

For any sub domain request, use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.band\.s\.example
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.band\.s\.example
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Just make some folder same as sub domain name you need.
Folder must be exist like this: `domain.example/sub` for `sub.domain.example`.

Comment: This works for me but it doesn't keep the file.
For example sub.domain.com/index.php throw 404

Answer (score -1):

Edit file *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is an HTTP to HTTPS (same host) redirect, which has nothing to do with the question.