# Subdomain showing directory content

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am devoloping a website with htaccess rules. This is the url structure:

```
example.com
example.com/index.php/login
example.com/index.php/foo
demos.example.com
```

For the last url above (demos.example) I would like to do show the content of `example.com/index.php/demos`, for this reason, I have create a .htaccess file as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?demos.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/demos [L]
```

When I browse `demos.example.com` the index page is displayed (example.com), as nothing had happended. I hope that my explanation has been clear.

- I have readed [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory), but this solution do a "browser redirection" and that is not the idea.
- Using [this example](http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2007/06/13/redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-directory-using-htaccess/) produces nothing: the index is displayed instead of index.php/demos

### Update

If I use the .htaccess as follow:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?demos\.example\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/demos/$1 [L]
```

...this make that the browser display a `500 internal server error`. Viewing the log, it prints the following messages:

```
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [error] [client 201.192.30.254] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 201.192.30.254] r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/demos/, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Dec 06 15:06:24 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /, referer: http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?demos\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php/demos/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This make a browser redirection instead for "point", as I mencioned in the post

Comment: Ah, so you want it to keep the URL intact, but show contents from another domain? I don't think it's possible actually.. Is it? I mean, I'm sure you should be able to do this via setting up a virtual server in your DNS records. But with .htaccess.. I doubt.

Comment: I think that it is posible. It is not from another domain, is just another "segment" from same domain.

Comment: Right, a subdomain. Okay, I'll be curious to see a solution myself then.

Comment: Well, It is not possible show content from another domain, but It is possible from the same domian (using the file name instead of full url). However, to make it works I has been a little hack but in the application side, nothing more to do with the .htaccess