# htaccess rewriting subdomain to php page

Tags: .htaccess, rewriting

I don't have experience in htaccess and failed to find solution for that.

Simply,
i want to make

```
something1.domain.com to open www.domain.com/something1.php
something2.domain.com to open www.domain.com/something2.php

& www.domain.com open www.domain.com/index.php
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com/%1.php [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1.php [L]
```

I am assuming you have allowed overrides using [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive in apache configuration. You have to [enable mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) if the redirect has to be transparent. If you do not want that then remove the ['L'](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag. The L flag prevents further processing of rules and immediately applies the rule that matched.

Comment: I found that AllowOverride is not enabled, i am on shared hosting, and i don't know how i can enable it. Any help ?

Comment: How did you find out the AllowOverride is not enabled? Usually in shared hosting you have to contact support to get any changes in the Apache configuration.

Comment: I contacted them, they replied that "The allowoverride is not needed, nor is it permitted" ....
 is there alternative solution ?

Comment: Well then you should be able to configure sub-domains to folders in c-panel and then have something*.php in the domain specific folders but as index.php.