# .htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory and keep subdomain in url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a subdomain to a subdirectory using .htaccess but keep the subdomain in the url like this:

Visited url in browser: `sub1.domain.com`

Served url: `sub.domain.com/sub1/`

I tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

but this leads to an endless loop. I know that it would be easier to do this by php but is there any  solution for this with using .htaccess?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this rule in document root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub1/).*)$ /sub1/$1 [L,NC]
```

**Explanation:**

- `NC`: Ignore case
- `L`: Last rule
- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` line makes sure that rule only executes for `subdomain`
- `(?!sub1/)` is negative lookahead expression that means of request is not starting with `/sub1/`
- `RewriteRule ^((?!sub1/).*)$ /sub1/$1 [L,NC]` rewrites current path to `/sub1/<uri>`

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thank you, but with this lines I get "Internal Server" on all domains and subdomains.

Comment: @MDeuerlein,That means you didn't setup subdomains correctly on your server.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this answer and I'm really confused that someone has said its working fine now - as the RewriteCond contains the literal string 'subdomain' but that was never part of the original question? And unfortunately these rules have to be 100% accurate or apache doesn't work!  Please can you review and correct accordingly?  thanks

Comment: It was indeed past of the op's coffee in the question and in any case the are just place holders as op didn't reveal actual domain name (justifiably). Please consider opening a different question if you are running into problems.

Comment: Finally...spent over an hour figuring out how to make a .htaccess which correctly handles domain and subdomains. This answer worked. Obviously you'll want to replace 'subdomain', 'domain', and 'sub1' with your data.

Comment: ugh. so fed up of all these answers - can someone give an answer that also explains what all the symbols are doing? for example, why the trailing dollar symbol, what is NC etc. Tried reading some documentation, it's like reading martian!

Comment: @bharal: I've added explanation and references in the answer. Spend some time reading manuals and ask a specific question if you have.

Comment: @anubhava I am truly grateful!

Comment: Does this require that we add an A or CNAME record in our DNS to the same server IP as the main domain website? And if the subdomain also needs to use HTTPS (secure) then will this rule work? Do I need to add this subdomain to our Let's Encrypt cert?

Comment: You just need a Virtual Host config to point subdomain to a sub directory of the same name