# PHP script that forwards by reading the subdomain WHILE using https

Tags: php, subdomain, forward, wildcard-subdomain

I've got a php script that forwards the user based on what subdomain the wrote in the url.

Now, normally you would read the HTTP_URI, but my webhost are using iframe, so I have to read the HTTP_REFERRER.

now to the problem, when accessing the site "normal", like mysite.com or

http://example.com

it works fine, however, when using https, it only shows a white page.

This is my code:

```
<?PHP

$REFERRER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// Or other method to get a URL for decomposition 
$domain = substr($REFERRER, strpos($REFERRER, '://')+3); 
$domain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '/')); 
// This line will return 'en' of 'en.example.com' 
$subdomain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '.')); 
//Echo $subdomain;

header("Location: https://example2.com/'$subdomain");
?>
```

.. Anybody got any suggestions?
Rewriting doesn't work on subdomains on this server.

Comment: You may find it easier to use the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Comment: Took me two weeks to get this one that worked (mostly)

Comment: Isn't that something one usually does on the protocol level, so inside the http server , not in php? Read: take a look at the http servers rewriting features.

Comment: What does "white page" mean? Which HTTP response code is used? Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: _“but my webhost are using iframe”_ - please properly explain what that actually means. _“it works fine,”_ - no it doesn’t, lots of clients don’t send a referrer. _“however, when using https, it only shows a white page”_ - might be due to a referrer policy, go check if anything like that is set.

Comment: @cbroe since my host are shared, they use iframe to forward subdomains to my main domain (no idea why), and because of that I need to use the referrer data, since that's the original requested url.

Comment: That’s shit hosting then ... I would first of all switch to one that offers a proper setup.

Comment: However, I've read somewhere (I don't remember where) that you have to do something with the script to process both https and http

Comment: Do you maybe have mixed content when using https? can you check the console.

Comment: @NicoHaase the "white" page is the sites iframe that's suppose to run my index.php, but nothing happens, I think the script isn't running on https.

Comment: @DomenikReitzner you got it right "blocked loading mixed active content"  no idea what it means, but that seems to be the error

Comment: It means you can not load a page with an iframe over https if anything in that iframe or itself is loaded over http

Comment: @Jerry, please mark your question as answered, since it is a hosting problem that you have no influence over.

Comment: Strange, because if I enter http://example.com it loads https://example2.com   ..   but https://example.com can't load https://example2.com..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the problem is "blocked loading mixed active content".

An iframe or its contents can not be loaded over http if the site containing the iframe is loaded via https.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your https rewrite in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and you can use this for the subdomain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub1/).*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394989/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory-and-keep-subdomain-in-url/22395008#22395008)