How can I create dynamic subdomains with laravel tenancy
I installed and configured https://tenancyforlaravel.com/ lib into my Laravel application. The problem is that after creating subdomain in tenants|domains tables I cannot access this subdomain from browser. I see "This site can’t be reached".
It is only accessible after 'hosts' file modification. How can I achieve dynamic subdomains here without adding them into 'hosts' file?
App itself is written in Laravel, and run in Docker. Web server - Nginx.
Thank you!

You'd need to point *.example.com at your server via DNS. Known as a "wildcard".

Thank you. I tried it already, but without "hosts" modification it still shows "This site can't be reached". Unfortunately wildcards don't work in hosts file. Any other idea?

An actual domain name, with actual DNS records.

@RuslanB Take a look on this method, i guess you can keep the reg laravel rules with subfolder and use htaccess to keep subdomain in the url, with litle modification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394989/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory-and-keep-subdomain-in-url
