# .htaccess Is Not working in Linux(Debian) Apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian

I am using **apache2** (my dummy server) which is already install with my **Debian**. Every thing goes fine, but now the problem with my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**It's not working** 
I think its because of **apache2** version which am I using & maybe problems with my code or something I have to **config** on my server

I want to **redirect** my  url to main index page if its a **wrong entry  or unavailable**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your urls? Change from what to what? Also why do you have two `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` of those in your code?

Comment: 2nd one is {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

Comment: Okay, and what about the url? What are you changing it from and changing to?

Comment: i want to change it other to index page

Comment: And do you want the old or new url shown?

Comment: i want the main index Old one if link is not available

Answer (score 32):

After spending a whole day, I got my answer

In Folder 
**apache2**>>**sites-available**>>  There is file called **default**

In default we have to change it

From:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

TO:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Its working. It's enabled use of .htaccess files.

Comment: Thx, thats work. But i changed it for Debian in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Have a note on the `Indexes` here. I will allow users to browse your image / css / js folders.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my case on CentOS7. But the file was `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have created the .htaccess with directives and also the .htpasswd file. I am accessing the file with no restrictions. What else do I need to do to password protect my website?

Comment: I added some bogus lines to my .htaccess. That prevented me from accessing my website. So the .htaccess is being read but it doesn't seem to work as far as requiring a user name and password.

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to add that `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load` needs to be enabled:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

On Debian I thought it was enabled by default, but mine wasn't.

Comment: It's useful to test if .htaccess is enabled first by breaking it (add garbage text) to produce a 500 error. Then, if .htaccess is working, but you still get 404 pages, this is likely the reason

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,R]
```

will redirect `http://example.com/test.php` to `http://example.com/index.php?url=test.php` if the file doesn't exist. The only difference between my code here and your one is I have [R] instead of [QSA,L] If it still doesn't work for you and you have the htaccess file in the root folder then, I don't think it's a htaccess file problem

Answer (score 1):

Important to note that `AllowOverride` only works in `<Directory>` directives and will be ignored if placed inside `<Location ...>` section; this was my issue and it took me for a nice ride.

> Only available in  sections AllowOverrideList is valid only
>   in  sections specified without regular expressions, not in
>   ,  or  sections.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride