# index.php issue with updated Debian on google cloud with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, debian, gcloud

Recently I have moved our 25 websites on Google cloud hosting successfully.

but today I am getting strange issue, after move a website (which is working fine on previously hosting) on Google cloud hosting. 
my WordPress categories suddenly stop working and it says 404 I tried everything changing permalinks replace .htaccess but no luck. I tried changing permissions all thing nothing worked.

I create a new instance with WordPress which is working fine with sub category and post working but with index.php like this `http://0.00.00.00/index.php/front-page/post-url/` (which reminds me yahoo hosting issue with WordPress).

This problem is same as I am having on my in-house server which is on already Debain os.

I need solution because I am not a Server administrator guy so if anyone having same issue or solution?

Answer (score 2):

got a solution and it worked [.htaccess Is Not working in Linux(Debian) Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797931/htaccess-is-not-working-in-linuxdebian-apache2)

in my case apache2 configuration file location is  **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

and i just replaced `AllowOverride None`  to `AllowOverride All` then restart apache service using following command
 `service apache2 restart`
after restart go to WordPress admin and remove **index.php** from permalink.