# Redirecting a subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a subdomain set up on my hosting: `indiantimes.indianradio.net.au`, that is being pulled from a folder in my `/public_html` folder: `/public_html/indiantimes.com.au`.

I am trying to write an .htaccess rule that will redirect it to that folder still, but retain the original url the user typed in: `indiantimes.indianradio.net.au`.

I have only been able to get the redirect working, i.e. (`indiantimes.indianradio.net.au` redirects to `indianradio.net.au/indiantimes.com.au/`), but I can't seem to get the redirect working so the url seen by the user, stays at: `indiantimes.indianradio.net.au`. The majority of the image urls are broken intil I am able to get the redirect working properly.

The .htaccess rule I was playing around with was:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^indiantimes\.indianradio\.net\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.indiantimes\.indianradio\.net\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/indianradio\.net\.au\/public_html\/indiantimes\.com\.au" [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong with the redirect? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace your sub folder name to be the same as your sub domain
 
(indiantimes.com.au -> indiantimes).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^indiantimes\.indianradio\.net\.au$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/indiantimes/
RewriteRule (.*) /indiantimes/$1
```

[source](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/01/redirect-sub-domain-to-sub-folder-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

for subdomains it is generally recommended to add a virtualhost in apache instead of using .htaccess (preformance-wise and more cross-platform).
However you might find the following link suitable in case editing the apache config files isn't an option: [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory) (summary: using mod-proxy and adding the P flag to your RewriteRule)

1. Go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (use `cd` in terminal)
2. Add a new file named: indiantimes.indianradio.net.au, example content:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/indianradio.net.au/public_html/indiantimes.com.au/
       ServerName indiantimes.indianradio.net.au

       <Directory /var/www/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
           AllowOverride None
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
       </Directory>


       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-logfile.log
       # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
       # alert, emerg.
       LogLevel warn
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-logfile.log combined

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. link to the file in apache2/sites-enabled

in terminal: `ln -s ./indiantimes.indianradio.net.au ../sites-enabled/` from the sites-available folder, note the trailing `/`!

Comment: This one is on shared hosting so I'm unable to use a virtualhost. I'm looking into the link you sent now, to see about modifying the htaccess. Thanks!

Comment: @McWayWeb You're welcome, note that almost all shared hosting accounts have an interface to add subdomains (in a correct way) though.
`RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/indianradio\.net\.au\/public_html\/indiantimes\.com\.au" [R=301,L]`
should be something along the lines of:
 `RewriteRule ^/indiantimes.com.au/$1 [R=301,L,P]` (untested, switched away from apache a while ago)