# Is there a WordPress plugin to manage subdomain URL mappings in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I have a subdomain setup in cPanel, like `example.domain.com`, and redirecting to `domain.com/blah/file`.

This works but of course the URL changes to the destination one and does not stick on the subdomain. It won't navigate anywhere as it is pointing to a holding / campaign page but not sure how I can get it to stay on subdomain name but pull in the URL I want it to.

Is there a WordPress addon to help with this, so it can be managed when creating these campaigns in the admin, or a way in cPanel?

Comment: I have simply setup the subdomain in cpanel control panel which allows redirection

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

Answer (score 0):

[Disable the redirection](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains#Subdomains-Enableordisablesubdomainredirection), [point the subdomain to the main document root](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains#Subdomains-Modifythedocumentrootforasubdomain) and edit the `.htaccess` in your main directory root to include:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Credit to [@Ansari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642616/1414639).

Comment: Would i place that within main site root? domain.com/ one?

Comment: @James, yep, and point the subdomain to the main document root. Obviously you need to change the `sub.domain.com` to your subdomain and `http://domain.com/subdomains/sub/` to the directiory you want to appear when you go to the sub-domain.

Comment: Also should i remove the subdomain and redirection in cpanel?

Comment: @James, you need to [disable redirection](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains#Subdomains-Enableordisablesubdomainredirection) and [point the subdomain to the main document root](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains#Subdomains-Modifythedocumentrootforasubdomain).

Comment: Super i will give it a go and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help, i will check it out now.