# How to have different subdomains as urls for different pages in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, subdomain

I have a single CI application hosted in say `abcd.com`
and it has different pages like

- abcd.com/pages/one
- abcd.com/pages/two
- abcd.com/pages/three

now the requirement is when user access `one.abcd.com` as url (in address bar) then it will display `abcd.com/pages/one` content

**EDIT :**  `but the url in address bar should remain` **one.abcd.com**

similarly `two.abcd.com` should display `abcd.com/pages/two` content

how that can be achieved ? as routing only accept the path name excluding domain

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.one.abcd\.com$
 RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/abcd\.com\/pages\/one" [R=301,L]

Comment: basically you can add rule in your htaccess file to achieve this

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory

Comment: do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: have this
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?abcd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.abcd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /pages/%1 [L]
```

This will only work if you have `*.abcd.com` all pointing to the same document root.

Comment: can u plz write the above rules specifically for `one.abcd.com` also
actually my regex knowledge is very poor

Comment: @Uttara it works for one.abcd.com, and two.abcd.com, and *anything*.abcd.com except www

Comment: yeah I know you have written the generic rule but just can u plz write it for specific one, and also I have pointed my subdomains to same IP as that of domain, but it shows 403 forbidden

Comment: @Uttara just replace `[^.]+` with `one`

Comment: its not working :( as I have pointed my `one.abcd.com` to same root folder as `abcd.com` hence when accessing `one.abcd.com` it displays the website from start, also plz look at my EDIT