# Force https:// cause problems in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I have a htaccess file that forces everything to load a specific https address.

We have two domains, lets say web.no and website.no.

web.no points to website.no, but i have a subdomain dev.web.no that i dont want to redirect to website.no

The rules is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://website.no/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How do I make an exception for dev.web.no?

Comment: i see [here][1] it's maybe the same question :D
goodluck

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dev.web.no
RewriteRule ^ https://website.no/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```