# Rewrite folder to subdomain using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, bitnami

My site structure is below;

```
index.php
blog/index.php
careers/index.php

wwww.mydomain.com === index.php
```

How can I get my subdomain to redirect to my sub folders;

```
blog.mydomain.com == blog/index.php
careers.mydomain.com == careers/index.php
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's dublicated. See this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory

Comment: Why not setup `/blog` as `DocumentRoot` for `blog` subdomain in virtual host config

Comment: can you advise how to do that please @anubhava

Comment: @moh.ABK You just set it in your virtual host as the document root. See this example.,http://serverfault.com/a/223793