# How to redirect domain in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to redirect page if the domain name with username ?

If I try "rodekruis.example.com" like this.. it should be redirect to "example.com/user/rodekruis". Is this possible ?

Here is my ".htaccess" file code..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried in route.php file like below

```
$route['rodekruis'] = 'user/overview/1510';
```

That is also not working

Comment: Have you looked at the uri routing for codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: yes. but no one is working I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a correct .htaccess redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomains/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-direc‌​tory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-direc%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btory)