# Htaccess Redirect : convert subdomain to part of a url

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example my domain is 
www.mydomain.com 
and I have subdomain like 
subdomain.mydomain.com/action?qs1=1

Now I have changed my previous subdomain URL to
www.mydomain.com/subdomain/action?qs1=1

Please let me know how to write rule in htaccess to redirect

subdomain.mydomain.com/action?qs1=1

to

www.mydomain.com/subdomain/action?qs1=1

Thanks

Comment: subdomain is dynamic for example it may be abc or xyz etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory

Comment: So you want URL to change in browser as well?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /action/\?qs1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/subdomain/action/ [NC,L,R]
```