# Can I access files from a subdomain into a parent domain?

Tags: subdomain

I created a subdomain inside the folder subdomain, when trying to read css from the parent directory (root) it is not working.

Is there some fix to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20387850/3808307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to specifiy the full path to the resource on the subdomain ( such as: 'http://subdomain.example.com/styles.css') since the root path will only point to the domain the site is hosted on.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was a way, thanks, I just didnt want to adjust my code since in localhost I have in a folder.

Comment: Will it read the database though? Or will I need a different database for the subdomain?