# redirect a subdomain to a different subdomain without changing the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

How do I redirect a class.11talk.net to http://eng.pinestalking.com/home/eng/index/index.html without changing the URL?

As of current I have htaccess redirect set up in subdomain class.11talk.net as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^class\.11talk\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.class\.11talk\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/eng\.pinestalking\.com\/home\/eng\/index\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```

301 redirection is easy but now I want the URL to remain as class.11talk.net but display content from http://eng.pinestalking.com/home/eng/index/index.html working as a proxy.

The two are obviously NOT from the same server.

Comment: There is no need to escape anything in the substitution URL. So just write `http://eng.pinestalking.com/home/eng/index/index.html`

Comment: As it happens, I answered a similar question recently, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39574451/1741542

Answer (score 0):

Use a full page iframe, .tk did this for years and it worked fine.

Other than that, point the DNS record to the other server and configure it to host that directory under this domain name.

Comment: class.11talk.net is responsive and I use an iframe like you recommended, it would go against that.