# Redirect subdomain to folder from home directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I will start by saying I no very little about htaccess. I would like a way for a subdomain like example.my-domain.com to use the files located in /example folder in home directory.  No matter what I try like sam.my-domain.com it shows a 404 error and does not load the index file in the "sam" directory.

**Steps I have done so far:**

- I created an A record in my DNS file *.my-domain.com
- I created an "example" folder and "sam" folder in my home directory.
- I made the edits to my htaccess file based on previous answers

This is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.my-domain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

How do I get any subdomain to automatically load the corresponding folder from the home directory?

*Information gathered from:*

[htaccess subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

[enable mod_rewrite for apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2/5758551#5758551)

[Apache Modules available on server](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/apache-modules-that-are-on-all-of-our-shared-servers)