# Linking a domain to a different server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I've been having trouble with my host (PcExtreme) with blocking several websites since they don't really accept forum software on their hosts. I tried to create a DNS record and link it to my own dedicated server but this didn't go that well...

The things I've tried is:

1. I created the DNS record to link from 'forum.xxx.xxx' to 'server ip'. This would indeed link to the dedicated server, the server isn't really doing a really great job because writing an htaccess to the right subfolder isn't working. I wanted to write an htaccess file to capture the domain, if the domain equaps to the 'forum.xxx.xxx' it would redirect to a subfolder, something like; 'project/forum'. This didn't work, it would keep giving me the basic homepage of apache (running wamp).
2. Creating an htaccess file on the domain's location to direct to the dedicated server resulted into one big mess. I don't even know what I was thinking when I was trying this, guess I was just out of options...

The infrastructure from the entire idea would come to this;

- user visits the domain; forum.xxx.xxx
- the server has a dns record from 'forum.xxx.xxx' to '0.0.0.0' (masked for the post)
- The files will be taken from the server '0.0.0.0' while staying on the domain 'forum.xxx.xxx'
- happy users, happy people.

Any push into the right direction would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution;

```
RewriteEngine On

#If the host is "sub.domain.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
#Then rewrite any request to /folder
RewriteRule ^((?!folder).*)$ /folder/$1 [NC,L]
```

All the credits should go to [starkeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160747/starkeen) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory).