# PHP .htaccess point subdomain to directory in root without redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to point (not redirect) a sub domain to a directory in the root domain. For example I have the following domain:

```
https://test.example.com
```

I would like that to point to the directory:

```
https://example.com/apple
```

This needs to happen without changing the URL from the subdomain. It also needs to include any URL parameters, example:

```
https://test.example.com/hello-world
```

Should point to (not redirect) to:

```
https://example.com/apple/hello-world
```

In my `.htaccess` file (in the root directory of the subdomain) I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apple$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/apple/$1
```

This works but it redirects. Any suggestions on how to point the sub domain to that directory without redirecting without using `mod_proxy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

Comment: @ponury-kostek all of those are redirects

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule I am assuming both domains are pointing at same location.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ apple/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question, I probably won't be able to turn on mod_proxy (it's a shared server).