# Pointing subdomain to public_html

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I would like to have the following:

**maindomain.com pointing to public_html/subfolder**

PLUS

**subdomain.maindomain.com pointing to public_html**

I managed to do the first on htaccess but don't know how to do the second.

Comment: Do you manage your server with CPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite role in Apache can be helpful. take a look at the following question:

[.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)