# Redirecting all subdomain requests to main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect all `subdomain` requests like `anytext.bday.life` to `bday.life/index.php`

I tried the following code on my `htaccess` file but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution for this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.bday\.life
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bday.life/index.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: what URLs are you trying when you test this out?

Comment: Please check the code now. I've edited it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

Comment: @Erik I already tried it and nothing happened. Do i need an advanced web hosting server for this feature?

Comment: create a file with

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

And see if mod_rewrite is in the list

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled. Because i have used this feature to redirect domain.com/query to domain.com/index.php?query=query