# How to add a subdomain for every user that registers with PHP on Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have created a basic signup/login form with PHP.

Now I want to let my website create a subdomain for every user signed up on my website.

For example, My domain is "mydomain.com" and "Tom Smith" registers through the 'register form' with his name. I would like my website to automatically create a subdomain: "tomsmith.mydomain.com".

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What server are you using? Apache or nginx? You could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory

Comment: @JayBee apache, but that question/answer doesn't really cover on how to do this automaticly.

Comment: @AryTuber just create/aflter the config files via normal file reading and writing