# Google Cloud Platform: External HTTPS load balancer and using variables in path redirect/value

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm configuring host and path rules for our GCP External HTTPS load balancer and I would like to know if it is possible to use variables for the path redirect/value?

Ultimately, I would like to match "something.cool.com" and have the user redirected to "www.cool.com/something" (the HTTP Location header)

[Host and path rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5gjT.png)

[Edit path rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHiX.png)

Comment: Afaik, you can only redirect/rewrite URLs for the same domain in GCP, otherwise - it'd be  CNAME or other DNS record. However, if you're using custom web server, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642616/12264548) might help you.

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, would love an answer to this