# Run the website on sub-folder on sub-domain from public folder without public path in URL

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8

Usually, I create a sub-domain and change the Document Root to the public folder like `public_html/subdomain/public` so when I visit https://subdomain.example.com it runs from the public folder without needing to add the public path in the URL.

Now I have a Laravel project on a sub-folder on a sub-domain `public_html/subdomain/subfolder` and I want to run the project from the public folder to avoid this https://subdomain.example.com/subfolder/public.

The website is hosted on a VPS server so I have access to everything.

How to make the project on the subfolder on the subdomain runs from the public folder without adding `/public` to the URL?

I tried this `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it appends `/public` to the URL.

Comment: That rule alone would not do that. Where is this .htaccess file? What other directives do you have? What other .htaccess files do you have? You appear to be rewritting to the wrong URL… what’s happened to the `/subfolder`?

Comment: is this the answer to your question? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642616/9739794

Comment: @MrWhite That .htaccess file is located in the subfolder directory `public_html/subdomain/subfolder/.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Move all the files which are in the **public_html/subdomain/subfolder** except public folder And make a new folder at **public_html/subdomain/main** which is

> main

and move all the files to the main folder after that move all files and folders from public to **public_html/subdomain/subfolder** and edit your index.php which will be looks like this

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../main/vendor/autoload.php';  // previous line require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../main/bootstrap/app.php'; // add main here also

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

You just need to edit 2 lines of code for that to work **require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';** to **require **DIR**.'/../main/vendor/autoload.php';**
And 2nd line is from **$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';** to **$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../main/bootstrap/app.php';**
And your folder structure should look like this
public_html/subdomain

```
├── subfolder
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── .htaccess
├── main
│   ├── app
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── config
│   ├── database
│   ├── resources
│   ├── routes
│   ├── storage
│   ├── tests
│   ├── vendor
│   ├── .env
│   ├── artisan
│   ├── composer.json
```